# Delete all folders, except specific folders and sub-folders

Tags: batch

I have a SSD with several partitions.
I need to work at J:\ and I need to delete everything inside J:, except the following folders:

```
J:\System Volume Information
J:\$RECYCLE.BIN
J:\New
J:\Old Stuff
```

And the following sub-folders:

```
J:\Papers\Folder
J:\Room\Main Documents
J:\Year\Origin\Part
J:\Year\Origin\Part Two
```

After searching and reading a lot, I wrote the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=J:\"
SET "keepdir=System Volume Information"
SET "keepdir=$RECYCLE.BIN"
SET "keepdir=New"
SET "keepdir=Old Stuff"
SET "keepdir=Papers\Folder"
SET "keepdir=Room\Main Documents"
SET "keepdir=Year\Origin\Part"
SET "keepdir=Year\Origin\Part Two"
FOR /d %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%keepdir%" RD /S /Q "%%a"
GOTO :EOF
```

Unfortunately, the code above doesn't work (it deletes everything inside J:).

Comment: You're overwriting `keepdir`, not adding to it.

Comment: @harrymc thank you. Please, what would be the right syntax for my code? I never wrote a batch before. I'm doing the best I can, reading here and there, copying and pasting, but I'm blind, I understand almost nothing about batch files. Please, can you tell me exactly how to avoid the keepdir overwriting? Hoe can I fix my code? Thank you again!

Comment: @Demet if you never wrote batch, why go for batch in the 1st place? PowerShellis much more powerful and easier to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bat
@echo off & cd /d J:\ || goto :eOf 

for /f ^delims^= %%i in =;('@dir /ogn /b /s /a:d
    ')do =;( type "%~f0" | 1>nul find /i "%%~fi" 
           );= || 1>nul 2>&1 rmdir /q /s "%%~fi"

goto :eof

:: Keep the list in the lines below the
:: full path of the folders that remained!

J:\New
J:\Old Stuff
J:\$RECYCLE.BIN
J:\Papers\Folder
J:\Year\Origin\Part
J:\Room\Main Documents
J:\Year\Origin\Part Two
J:\System Volume Information
```

---

**1.** Use a batch with a list of the folders you want to keep:

```bat
J:\New
J:\Old Stuff
J:\$RECYCLE.BIN
J:\Papers\Folder
J:\Year\Origin\Part
J:\Room\Main Documents
J:\Year\Origin\Part Two
J:\System Volume Information
```

**2.** Use a loop to list your folder tree

```bat
for /f ^delims^= %%i in =;('@dir /ogn /b /s /a:d
    ')do
```

**3.** For each folder in the loop, use a type in the bat itself and check if the folder/path appears there:

```bat
type "%~f0" | 1>nul find /i "%%~fi"
```

**4.** For cases where the folder/path is not found (`||`) in your bath, delete it:

```bat
type ...  find .. || rmdir /q /s "%%~fi"
```

**5.** Finishing the loop, exit the file:

```bat
goto :eOf
```

---

Some further reading:

- **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**
- **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
- **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
- **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
- **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**
- **[Use parentheses/brackets to group expressions in a Windows batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

1. Do `J:\> dir /s /b /ad >DirsToRemove.bat`
   to list **all** DIRS on J: (current drive) into the DirsToRemove.bat
   file.
2. Edit that file,
   Notepad works (not Wordpad), but a more advanced text editor is to prefer.
3. On every line add `rmdir /s /q` before the dirname,
   enclose the name in `"` -quotes if there is SPACE-characters in the name,
   using quotes on ALL names is also OK. => `rmdir /s /q "name"`
   *A more advanced text editor allows to use macros; using a macro might be as easy as starting recording, editing one line, stop recording - then use a shortcut key to launch the macro as many times as you wish.*
4. Remember to REMOVE the lines having dirs you wish to KEEP.
5. Save, then...
6. do `J:\> .\DirsToRemove.bat`

*When you have done similar things a few times, it usually takes just a minute or two to accomplish the task you have at hand.*

Comment: Firstly, thank you @Hannu for your well detailed answer. Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work. When I run "cmd /c DirsToRemove.bat", for each folder to be deleted, the batch asks "Are you sure Y/N", and when I enter "Y" nothing happens. I tested several times, and I did take care about the syntax. Please, I would like your help. Thank you again.

Comment: I have added `/-p` above, this should be a way to stop that querying, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/erase - it might be that the `del` command did not get your answers (key press'es) due to running inside separate `cmd.exe` instance.

Comment: `Del` is for files and has `/p /-p` flag support, `RMDir` or `RD` is for Directories/Folders and no `/p /-p` flag is supported.  You can verify this in *just a minute or two* using `Del /?` and `RMDir /?`. And there's no need to run `J:\> cmd /c DirsToRemove.bat`, just `DirsToRemove.bat`. You can also check that using `cmd /?`

Comment: rmdir it is... `rm -rf dir` for dirs in Linux, `rm file` for files. (I'm a Linux user ;-)